# Excel - How to hide rows based on various criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two spreadsheets.

Spreadsheet A is an item list of all the items stored in a warehouse.

Spreadsheet B is a list of all the items from a specific company.

Spreadsheet A is a very large spreadsheet, all the items on Spreadsheet B should also be on A.

What I have to do, for every item in Spreadsheet B, find that item on Spreadsheet A, take one cell of information on that item from Spreadsheet A and add it to Spreadsheet B.

This is easy enough to do manually, just copy the UPC of the item on Spreadsheet B, Ctrl+F it on Spreadsheet A to find the item and then copy the information I need back over to Spreadsheet B.

But doing that one-by-one for every item is going to take days of work. There's got to be an easier/faster way but I don't know how to do it. I don't even know where to ask about that sort of thing, that's why I'm here.

Is there a way I can hide all of the items from Spreadsheet A that aren't also in Spreadsheet B? That would be the easiest way for me to do that, but I don't know how hide rows of a spreadsheet based on a set criteria.

Here are examples of the spreadsheets so you can see what I'm talking about.

This is Spreadsheet A:

[image]

This is Spreadsheet B:

[image]

I need to be able to match the UPCs on both spreadsheets and then copy the UIN from Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B. It seems like there should be an easy way to do this, but I don't know what it is.

P.S. To get the UPC on Spreadsheet B you have to combine columns G + H or I

Comment: What do you mean? I can see them.

Comment: Do you know how to use a `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: Which field are you using as the lookup key? `Item`? Or is it a combination of fields?

Comment: I would use the Power Pivot Add-In, add the two tables to the Power Pivot Model then use the CALCULATE function to compare them e.g. http://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/profiling-data-in-powerpivot-comparing-two-tables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your task and your question are a bit different.

#### To answer your question:

You need to compare two tables by the key column *UPC*, mark the rows that match on sheet "*Spreadsheet A*" as `found`. Then apply autofilter to table A by column "*found*".

You can find the details on how to compare two sheets using formulas in the article [compare two columns remove duplicates](http://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/09/05/compare-two-columns-remove-duplicates/#two-columns-different-worksheets).

Then you need to compare manually.

#### A better way to solve the task:

Compare two tables by UPC column with the help of `Vlookup` formulas or special add-ins that copy the needed data from Sheet A to Sheet B automatically.

If you choose `Vlookup`, it will take about 10 minutes regardless the size of the table. If you use an add-in it will take even less time. You can find more details in [this vlookup article](http://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2011/12/14/lookup-excel-functions-vlookup/) and this [merge article](http://www.ablebits.com/excel-lookup-tables/howto-merge-data.php)

Comment: 10 minutes for a vlookup regardless of table size? You must have a very slow machine :)

Comment: 10 minutes for all of it :) - understanding vlookup basics, writing formulas and getting the result.

Comment: Okay, I tried using Vlookup and I can't figure it out. It seems to pull random data unrelated to anything I specified.

Comment: The formula I'm using is `=VLOOKUP($I26554,$G$2:$J$26550,4)` so it should find the value from `I26554` in cell `G144` and return the value in `J144`. But it doesn't; it returns the value in `J23174`, a seemingly completely random row since the value from `I26554` isn't anywhere nearby. I'm probably going to have to open another question for this.

Comment: In order for VLOOKUP to work correctly, the first column of the Table_array (col G in this case) must be sorted in ascending order. Also, I think you want to take the dollar sign off of the Lookup_value.